# uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{' :

Tags: jquery, mongodb, nosql

I just wrote this code (Mongodb):

```
db.items.update( {tags:"consola", precio:{$gte:100}}, {$set:{estado:"vendido", {$addToSet:{contraoferta:{email: "jpepito@gmail.com", psw: "jpepito", oferta: 800, fecha:new Date("2020, 3, 9")}}}}})
```

but the console just gave me this error:

> uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{' :
> @(shell):1:79

Look and look but can't find the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you executed this query but for me, I've executed almost the same query directly with `--eval` then I got the same kind of error

```
mongo --eval "db.getCollection('myCollection').updateMany({}, {$set:{locked:false}})"
```

Here is the error I got `uncaught exception: SyntaxError: expected property name, got ':' :`

But when I added "\" before "$set" It just went through without any error

```
--eval "db.getCollection('myCollection').updateMany({}, {\$set:{locked:false}})"
```

The 1st request is OK without error inside the mongo shell, I only got this issue with `eval` option

Comment: is it possible to exclude last two created documents ?

Comment: @YoussefBoudaya I'm not sure to get what you mean

Comment: in update many i want to exclude the last two documents from the operation

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know the syntax of this, but I suppose that `{$addToSet:` is wrong because this is not the property of a valid object. There had to be before this anything like `xyz:` or the `{`is here wrong.

So this looks perhaps better:

```
db.items.update( {tags:"consola", precio:{$gte:100}}, {$set:{estado:"vendido", $addToSet:{contraoferta:{email: "jpepito@gmail.com", psw: "jpepito", oferta: 800, fecha:new Date("2020, 3, 9")}}}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you missed some brackets that should close another brackets at column 79.